# How do I set Firefox 10.0.7 to always open link in new tab?

Tags: firefox

I am wondering if there is a way in Firefox 10.0.7 to set the it so every time I click on a link it opens it in a new tab.  I went to configuration mania and options and could not find it anywhere.  I also checked on the `about:config` and found the `browser.link.open_newwindow` but was unsure what to change the value to to set it so new tabs are opened every time a link is clicked on.

Comment: I use  "TabMixPlus" add-on. It has lots more options. By the way FF is now at 15.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try this simple add-on [Open Link in New Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-link-in-new-tab/) - it enforces link opening in new tab (or allows you to define some simple conditions also, if needed).